# Google Script Apps - 'Getting Started' Tutorial - Syntax Error

Tags: google-apps-script

I was following the example of making a simple map using Google Apps Script and copy-pasted the example code into my own script editor, from docs & sheets. When trying to run it though, it gives an error;

Syntax error. (line 11, file "Code")

The program looks like this;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%; /* This is line 11 */
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
          zoom: 8
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, what is the proper syntax?

Removing the

```
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

didn't affect it.

I tried including my own API key and leaving it as it is above, in case that changed anything, but it didn't.

[Here is the link to the tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

I feel like I'm making my inexperience obvious by saying what changes I tried, but in case anyone suggests those changes, now they know I've tried it. I think it's bizarre that googles own examples don't work. I've had issues with another example, the one about placing markers on various addresses.

Comment: The code snippet is for * .html files, maybe you are using the wrong extension ( *.gs).
See the link above the code, **(map-simple.html)** in tutorial's page.

Comment: *"When trying to run it though, it gives an error"* - Could you please let us know how you're trying to run it? Because what you have shown is HTML, and should be opened in a web browser.

Comment: Both of you were right, I should've been opening it in a browser, and not saved with a .gs extension. Would you recommend I delete this question since it's answer is mostly unrelated to the issue I thought I had?